# jquery ajax multiple upload tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I can find a lot of plugins that allow me to use one html input tag to upload multiple files but I want is to have multiple html input tags for the files but only one ajax call.

Can I have only one ajax call for uploading the files?

Here is an example of my html:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>test Files</legend>
    <label for="testFile">Test File
        <span class="small">Change the test file.</span></label>
    <input name="testFile" type="file"/>
    <label for="iconFile">Test Icon File
        <span class="small">Change the test icon.</span></label>
    <input name="iconFile" type="file"/>
    <label for="featuredFile">Test Featured File
        <span class="small">Change the test featured.</span></label>
    <input name="featuredFile" type="file"/>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Valmus ajax upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) which allows the selection of multiple files and uploading them via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

They could all call the same function that then uploads the file.